# I want to search data from a api and show its result

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, search

Html Code , string is passed to q , now i'm blank how to get data on my front end.

```
 <div class="ui search">
   <form class="example" action="/dashboard" method="get">
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter The Book Name to Search" class="prompt" name="q">
    <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</form>
    <div class="results"></div>
</div>
```

How to write scipt tag , how to retrieve data from api
please help guys

link : https://openlibrary.org/search?q={query string}

```
<script>

$('.ui.search')
    .search({
        apiSettings: {
            url: 'https://openlibrary.org/search?q={query}'
        },
        fields: {
            results : 'items',
            title   : 'name',
            url     : 'html_url'
        },
        minCharacters : 3
    })
;
```

Comment: What you tried so far? Nobody can help you with this kind of a question.

Comment: How to get data from api,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you apply css according to your will, this will work for fetching data

```
<div id="multiple-datasets">
            <form class="example" action="#">
        <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Enter The Book Name to Search" name="search">
            </form>
        </div>
```

> put this in your script tag

```
<script>
var books = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace,
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
        url: 'http://openlibrary.org/search.json?title=%QUERY',
        wildcard: '%QUERY',
        filter: function (searchResults) {
            return $.map(searchResults.docs, function (searchResults) {
              //  console.log(searchResults.author_name);
               // console.log("key is "+searchResults.key)
                if (JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("selectedBooks") == undefined || JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("selectedBooks").indexOf(searchResults.title)) == -1)){
                    return {
                        title: searchResults.title,
                        key: searchResults.key,
                    };
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
var authorsList = [];
var authors = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace,
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
        url: 'http://openlibrary.org/search.json?author=%QUERY',
        wildcard: '%QUERY',
        filter: function (searchResults) {
            return $.map(searchResults.docs, function (searchResults) {
                if (searchResults.author_name !== undefined){
                    var author = searchResults.author_name.toString();
                }
                if (authorsList.indexOf(author) == -1) {
                    authorsList.push(author);
                    return {
                        author_key: searchResults.author_key,
                        author: author,
                    };
                }
            });
        },
    }
});
$('#multiple-datasets .typeahead').typeahead({
        highlight: true
    },
    {
        name: 'books',
        display: 'title',
        source: books,
        templates: {
            header: '<h3 class="search">Books</h3>'
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'authors',
        display: 'author',
        source: authors,
        templates: {
            header: '<h3 class="search">Authors</h3>'
        }
    });

$('#multiple-datasets').bind('typeahead:selected', function(obj, datum, name) {
    if (name == 'books'){
        var selectedBooks = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("selectedBooks"));
        if (selectedBooks == null){
            var a = [];
            a.push(datum.title);
            sessionStorage.setItem("selectedBooks", JSON.stringify(a));
        }else{
            selectedBooks.push(datum.title);
            sessionStorage.setItem("selectedBooks", JSON.stringify(selectedBooks));
        }

    }else if (name == 'authors'){

        var selectedAuthors = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("selectedAuthors"));
        if (selectedAuthors == null){
            var a = [];
            a.push(datum.author);
            sessionStorage.setItem("selectedAuthors", JSON.stringify(a));
        }else{
            selectedAuthors.push(datum.author);
            sessionStorage.setItem("selectedAuthors", JSON.stringify(selectedAuthors));
        }
    }
    $('.typeahead').typeahead('val','');
    update_lists(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("selectedAuthors")),JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("selectedBooks")));
});

update_lists(JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("selectedAuthors")),JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("selectedBooks")));



function update_lists(Authors,Books) {
    $('#authorlist li').remove();
    $('#booklist li').remove();
    $.each(Authors, function(index,name) {
       // console.log("Its author data"+authors.name);
        $('#authorlist').append('<li><a href="#" >'+name+'</a></li>')
    });
    $.each(Books, function(index,name) {
        console.log("Book Data"+books);
        $('#booklist').append('<li><a href="#" >'+name+'</a></li>')
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this by using only HTML code. When you submit your form, the form inputs are sent to the server and page being refreshed. You can't handle the server response in this case.

If you really wanted to get the response in Javascript (without the page refreshing), then you'll need to use AJAX, and when you start talking about using AJAX, you'll need to use a library. jQuery is by far the most popular library. There's a plugin for [jQuery](http://jquery.com) called [Form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) which will do exactly what it sounds like you want.

Example:

```js
// wait for the DOM to be loaded 
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("Thank you for your 1!");
    // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
    // attach handler to form's submit event 
        $('#myForm')
      .ajaxForm({
          url : $('#myForm').attr('action'), // or whatever
          dataType : 'json',
          success : function (response) {
              alert("The server says: " + JSON.stringify(response));
          }
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>

<form id="myForm" action="https://httpbin.org/get" method="get"> 
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" /> 
    Comment: <textarea name="comment"></textarea> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" /> 
</form>
```